# How can I disable Chrome opening the Windows on-screen keyboard when debugging as iPad?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome-devtools

**When I open the Chrome debug view and set the device to "iPad Mini" to simulate its screen size (and touch events), interacting with a text input causes the Windows on-screen keyboard to open.**

This computer is not a tablet, and has never had a touch screen.  In the Windows `Ease of Access -> Keyboard` settings `Turns on the On-Screen Keyboard` is off.

I can only assume that Chrome "simulating" an iPad Mini is causing Windows to think there's a touchscreen.  I've been using this feature for a few months now, and the keyboard opening only started happening recently.  I may have simply flipped a switch in the settings (of Chrome or Windows) on accident.  If that's the case, I'd like to know how to flip it back!

This is frustrating because I have to close the keyboard each time as it covers up a large portion of the web-app.

[image: Keyboard opening]

The same page without the "iPad Mini" simulation does not open the keyboard:

[image: Keyboard does not open]

(This keyboard also opens when choosing any device that has a touch screen, not just iPad Mini.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome doesn't emulate the keyboards of the device profiles you pick. An image of a keyboard will show for certain ones, like the iPhone 5X, but it is non-functional and is just present to allow you to see how the various elements on the page respond to the keyboard. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392047/1814840) for more details on viewing that. However, this is not the same  keyboard you are seeing.

It looks as though there is something in Windows, which is triggering the on-screen keyboard. I'm not sure why it would still appear if you have it disabled, but you could try a couple of things, based on what I've found online:

1. Make sure 'Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service' is set to disabled in Services (services.msc)
2. Set`LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\ ShowTabletKeyboard` from value 1 to 0 (regedit.exe)
3. Check there is no other 3rd party software running, which may affect your keyboard behaviour.

Comment: Disabling the service did the trick.  I didn't think that would be necessary since the switch is off in Windows settings, and the keyboard never appears for any other reason in any application.  It's all fixed now!

Comment: FWIW, I had to disable the service, not just stop it and put it into Manual mode. In Manual mode it would get turned back on somehow automatically. Disable kept it off.